# Decrypting an encoded base64 into a token to extract claims using AES-CBC in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I am currently working on an authentication from an external third party that sends us an encoded base64 string which we -in turn- should decode it and then, decrypt it to fetch the user claims. Here is the method I created in C# to decrypt the value we receive from them:

```
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secretKey);
byte[] iv;

using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
{
    var decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(_jwtEncryptedToken);

    iv = new byte[16];
    Array.Copy(decodedBytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

    aesAlg.Key = key;
    aesAlg.IV = iv;
    aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);


    using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(decodedBytes))
    {
        using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
            {
                return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to test it along with the encoded base64 I receive, it always returns an error saying that, "Input data is not a complete block"

P.S. The secret key is of a 16 characters and the _jwtEncryptedToken is the encoded base64 that I receive

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you *sure* the first 16 bytes are the IV? If so, the AES encrypted part starts at byte 17 while your code tries to decrypt the IV as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No. I don't know about the IV being the first 16 characters. It was asked to be initialized as an array of 16 bytes

Comment: In that case you're missing vital information and can't decrypt anything. You can't just use random data. The IV buffer must be the same for both encryption and decryption.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Fair point. So is this IV always included in the encoded base64?

Comment: With CBC, an incorrect IV during decryption only leads to a corrupted first block (the first 16 bytes), i.e. the subsequent blocks of longer ciphertexts are decrypted correctly. If the rest of longer ciphertexts is also corrupted, this indicates other or additional problems.

Comment: @Topaco any idea what other problems would be as per the code?

Comment: If IV and ciphertext are actually concatenated, both must be separated. Although you get the IV, you still decrypt the concatenation IV|ciphertext. Instead, only the ciphertext may be decrypted, see here https://dotnetfiddle.net/uQAH6B.

Comment: If this does not work, the logic/algorithm used for encryption are different or it's due to your data (wrong key, corrupted ciphertext etc.). You can try to change parameters, but this is just guesswork. For a targeted implementation of the decryption code you need the related encryption code (or a detailed description of the encryption).

Comment: `using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(decodedBytes, 16, decodedBytes.Length - 16))` to skip the first 16 bytes. Also are you sure it's CBC and PKCS7?

Comment: What is the *actual* payload? The name `_jwtEncryptedToken` suggests it's an encrypted JWT (JWE?). The structure is [defined in RFC 7516](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7516#page-8) and the IV is *not* the first 16 bytes. If that's actually the case, there are .NET classes that handle JWT encryption and decryption, like [JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DecryptToken Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.decrypttoken?view=msal-web-dotnet-latest) and NuGet packages like Jose-JWT

Comment: JWTs use certificates and public key crytpography for signing or encryption, not shared keys. In the JWE standard the key itself is part of the token, encrypted using a public key encryption. If the JWT doesn't follow the standard, you'll have to find out the actual structure. You can't just guess which parts are the key, IV, payload or extra headers

Answer (score -2):

For decryption you need the Key and the initialization vector IV.

It is not clear if the Message to decryption is after the IV or it is in another variable.

Considering you received IV and Message in separated way

```
string decryptAES(string EncodedToken, string EncryptedMSG)
{
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secretKey); 
    byte[] iv;

    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        var decoded_IV_Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(EncodedToken);
        var toDecodeBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedMSG);

        iv = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(decoded_IV_Bytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

        aesAlg.Key = key;
        aesAlg.IV = iv;
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(toDecodeBytes))
        {
            using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

note that the IV is encoded with base64, but it is not encrypted.

try the code with:

```
string _secretKey = "1234567890abcdef";
decryptAES("ZmVkY2JhMDk4NzY1NDMyMQ==", "a4/W0T6oxPGbqsHbx3N1gA==");
```

Considering you received IV and Message concatenated

```
public static string decryptAES2(string EncryptedMSG)
{
    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_secretKey);
    byte[] iv;
    byte[] toDecodeBytes;

    using (var aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        var decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedMSG);
        iv = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(decodedBytes, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length);

        toDecodeBytes = new byte[decodedBytes.Length - 16];
        Array.Copy(decodedBytes, 16, toDecodeBytes, 0, decodedBytes.Length - 16);

        aesAlg.Key = key;
        aesAlg.IV = iv;
        aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(toDecodeBytes))
        {
            using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

try the code with:

```
string _secretKey = "1234567890abcdef";
decryptAES2("ZmVkY2JhMDk4NzY1NDMyMWuP1tE+qMTxm6rB28dzdYA=");
```

Comment: It's not necessary to do the extra copy, you can do `using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(decodedBytes, 16, decodedBytes.Length - 16))`

Comment: I know and I can do the same with much less code, But I'm keeping it closer to the original